# How to get the rect() of a dynamic circle

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am trying to get the rect of the circle in the draw method but Pygame gives an error everytime I call the get_rect() method on my Alien instance. I want a dynamic circle surface for collision detection because my code generates different random size of circles. Please any help will be greatly appreciated

```
class Alien():
    def __init__(self, etc):
        self.x = random.randrange(0,600)
        self.y and self.size are also random variables

def draw(self, screen, colour):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colour, (self.x, self.y), self.size)
```

I want to get the rect of this circle from the draw method but it doesn't have a rect method. I checked online and i saw you could use pygame.surface but I don't know how to use it to generate a surface for my circle taking into consideration that when I generate 20 different Alien circle object, they w

Comment: I honestly don't understand your question. I'd stick to the typical minimal example code along with a description of what happened and what you expected instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***All* drawing functions** of the [`pygame.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html) module **return a rectangle** representing the bounding area of changed pixels.

Update your `draw()` method

```
def draw(self, screen, colour):
    return pygame.draw.circle(screen, colour, (self.x, self.y), self.size)
```

to **return a `pygame.Rect` object** which you could use e.g. for collision detection.